# Populating array with objects from looping through checked radio buttons gives same value each time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code below:

```
$(".day_a_radio").change(function()     
    var radio_array = [];
    var radio_object = {};

    $("input.day_a_radio:checked").each(function() {
        radio_object["id"] = $(this).data("id");
        radio_object["date"] = $(this).data("date");
        radio_object["type"] = $(this).data("type");

        radio_array.push(radio_object);
    });

    console.log(radio_array);
```

I have a few dozen radio buttons with data attributes of id, date and type. When one of them is clicked, I loop through them all. Then within that loop, for each one that is checked, I populate an array with objects.

However, when I do the console.log, the ID, date and type are all the same despite all the radio buttons having different values

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: You're updating the same object each iteration.  You need to create a new object each iteration

Answer (score 3):

You have to make a new object, otherwise the same one is updated and pushed repeatedly.

```
$(".day_a_radio").change(function(){
    var radio_array = [];
    var radio_object = {};

    $("input.day_a_radio:checked").each(function() {
        // MAKE A NEW OBJECT
        radio_object = {};
        radio_object["id"] = $(this).data("id");
        radio_object["date"] = $(this).data("date");
        radio_object["type"] = $(this).data("type");

        radio_array.push(radio_object);
    });
```

You could also simplify this a little with a map.

```
$(".day_a_radio").change(function(){
    var radio_array = $("input.day_a_radio:checked").map(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        return {
            id: $this.data("id"),
            date: $this.data("date"),
            type: $this.data("type")
        };
    }).get();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're pushing the `same reference` to array every time you need to create a new copy every time and than push

```
$(".day_a_radio").change(function()     
    var radio_array = [];

    $("input.day_a_radio:checked").each(function() {
        var obj = {}   // It creates a new object everytime
        obj["id"] = $(this).data("id");
        obj["date"] = $(this).data("date");
        obj["type"] = $(this).data("type");

        radio_array.push(obj);
    });

    console.log(radio_array);
```